# Xcode 9 Static Library compatible with older Xcode versions

Tags: objective-c, xcode9

I have a static library along with a resource bundle (for holding assets and storyboards). To make my UI compatible with iPhone X (safe area), I am building these targets with Xcode 9.

However when I import this into a project created with Xcode 8, I get a framework missing error:

```
framework not found fileprovider for architecture x86_64
```

I understand that the FileProvider framework is not available in Xcode 8.

1) Since I am not using the FileProvider framework in my code, is it possible to create the library that does not link to FileProvider?

2) Is it possible to create the library from Xcode 8 and still use the safe area constraints?

Comment: You can link framework as optional

Comment: You can use safe area constraints if your deployment target is ios 11. In which xcode you have builded library doesn't matter, if it written on objective-c.

Comment: @Cy-4AH That is exactly the problem. safe area constraints only seem to be available in Xcode 9 and you can target iOS 11 only from Xcode 9 not Xcode 8.

Comment: If you main idea wast to write static library in Xcode 9 that uses safe area constraints and link it with Xcode 8 project with deployment target lower then ios 11, that will not work. You  will need use availability check and implement code with safe area constraints for ios 11 and with top/bottom layout guides for other. Or you can just use top/bottom layout guides. They are working yet.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Yes I can only target iOS 9 and above in that case. Also top/bottom layouts are not the issue, leading and trailing cause issues in landscape mode.